# Unable to store ID of an element in variable jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am doing a project where I have a unordered list with a tags within it and currently need to access the id of the `li` which I am mousing over, but the output of the alert gives me `undefined` or just blank.

**JavaScript**:

```
$("ul#menu li").mouseover(function(){
      var current_id = $(this).attr("id")
      alert(current_id);
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<ul id="menu">
   <li>
      <a class="exclude" id="testvideo1" href="#">1</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a class="exclude" id="testvideo2" href="#">2</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a class="exclude" id="testvideo3" href="#">3</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The id is in the `<a` not in the `<li`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it is showing `undefined` is because `$(this)` is representing the `li` tag and the `a` which is containing the `id` what you are looking for.

Maybe you can try with the following:

```
$('ul#menu li').mouseover(function() {
  var current_id = $(this).find('a').attr('id');
  alert(current_id);
});
```

Read further here: [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

Based on [@AlonEitan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/754119/alon-eitan)'s comment it is better to use `.children()` instead of `.find()`. Found the following in the documentation:

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.

So you can also do like the following:

```
$('ul#menu li').mouseover(function() {
  var current_id = $(this).children('a').attr('id');
  alert(current_id);
});
```

Read further here: [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

I hope this helps!

Comment: I don't recommend `find()` in this case, but `children()` buecase _`.children()` only travels **a single level** down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels_ - So `find` will cause problems in case of nested lists

Comment: @AlonEitan Good catch, just updated my answer! Thanks!

Comment: @Red Happy to help, please consider accepting as the answer if it resolved your problem, thank you!

Comment: @Red Don't forget to accept this answer by clicking on the `✓` icon next to the answer :)

Comment: That is not a good reason at all to use `children`, in fact the opposite! I recommend `find` because it is much better programming practice to code defensively - another developer on your team might change the html and so using `children` would break. An even better idea is to use a class name and `find` that rather than relying on the `a` tag.